# Is there a way/framework to track the SMS (Number/day) and Call data (Minutes/day) on a normal iPhone (Not Jailbroken)

Tags: iphone, ios, frameworks, core-telephony

I am a beginner iOS developer and I am trying to build an app which tracks the users SMS (Number) and Call data (Minutes/day) only but have no clue which framework to use. CoreTelephony is of no use as per my knowledge. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Call Statistics and SMS Statistics are handled by the cell carrier, but are also recorded by the phone and are visible in the settings application. However, there is no way for your app to access this information (as far as i know). **It would be a privacy concern and probably won't ever be available.** Im sure there is a way to do it on a jailbroken device, but it sounds like thats not what you want. What exactly does your app do?

Comment: Yes, I have seen quite a few frameworks on Jailbroken iPhone however I want to access the data on normal iPhones. I want to show the SMS stats (Number only) and minutes spent over call to the user. This would be a medical app and analyze this passive data collected and would be available to researchers

Comment: I don't know of a way to get the SMS stats. Maybe something here could help: http://iosstuff.wordpress.com/2011/08/19/accessing-iphone-call-history/

Comment: Apple has no motivation or reason to allow this behavior.  This information is private to the user.  "This information would be available to researchers" sounds shady, even if it actually isn't.

Comment: @Unicorn - The link wont work since they (Apple) fixed it after iOS 5.0 and call data database is no more available freely...

Comment: Well then it sounds like you won't be able to do what you would like to do.

Comment: http://www.mspy.com/buynow.html?utm_expid=77466971-48.PiOcvobASCy8uwRkDaBT9A.0&utm_referrer=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mspy.com%2Fno-jailbreak.html   How mspy does it?